# Dynamic values issue in high chart

Tags: php, highcharts

I want to use dynamic values in xAxis Category and Series Data. But when i use through an array than my chart is not working and no error occurred.

Here is my code:

```
var visitor_id = new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');

var total_visit_count = new Array(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6);

$('#graph_main').highcharts({
   title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [visitor_id]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [total_visit_count]
            }]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mistake lies here

```
data: [total_visit_count]
```

it should be

```
data: total_visit_count
```

total_visit_count is an array and data accepts a array but you are passing the  entire array as array with in an array.

hope this helped you

Comment: Thank you for your answer and support regarding this issue, its working now.